# Protecting a smartphone from rain?

Tags: phone, cell-phone

I have a 5.5 inch smartphone,but it's not water proof and i face problem when i am cycling and it rains. I tried searching a polythene cover but alas i am unable to find a slim cover for the phone.Any other method/hacks i can do in order to avoid this problem?

Comment: Even though i have accepted an answer but still it is open for new ideas!, like it's a bit awkward to carry that,well i think of a balloon now :) , so any other new idea which can do is welcome and grateful !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a **condom**!

Place your phone in a condom and tie the end. This works even if you submerge it in water. :)

[image: Condom Phone]

Comment: Just brilliant. The kids will be surprised what watertight phone bags are good for, when they grow older :) I wonder how well you can use the touch screen like this.

Comment: Just make sure to use high quality condoms. Some condoms are easily punctured leaving the user in great despair. :)

Comment: @JemEripol - in that case I'd be _so happy_ to have used it for a phone!

Comment: Hahaha. A good excuse if your mother discovers one in your wallet! :)

Comment: If the condom is a good tight fit the touch will still work fine. (Please don't quote me out of context. :-) )

Answer (score 3):

Ziplock freezer bags also work well.